# How to create a new column with random strings in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to add a new column to my dataframe with random strings, how do I conform the output of `randomword` to input of `withColumn`

```
def randomword(length):
   letters = string.ascii_lowercase
   return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

df_with_new_col = mydf.withColumn('random_string', randomword(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=N))
```

`random.choices` Python 3.6+